# Use all the elements of the table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a table in the page "map.blade.index.php" as:

```
<table id="table">
<thead> 
<tr><th>ID</th> 
<th>Name</th> 
<th>Latitude</th>
<th>Longitude</th>
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody><tr>
<td>0</td>
<td id="0">Name 174</td>
<td id="lat0">41.1230199</td>
<td id="lng0">14.73767010000006</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and I try to use the table elements in my function Controller called "MapController@saved" , but I think  that I can't use the table by her id. 
there a way to use all the elements of the table ? Now I must use one item at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your table with any HTML parser. I'm using [this one](https://github.com/yangqi/Htmldom).

```
$html->find('td[id=lat0]')->innertext; // Returns 41.1230199
```

Comment: after this, can I use it in my controller? Can i use a loop for X elements?

Comment: Sure you can. It's pretty cool and easy to use (after you learn how to use it) tool.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood then what you need is a multi input like:

```
<form action="map/saved">
    <table id="table">
        <thead> 
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th> 
                <th>Name</th> 
                <th>Latitude</th>
                <th>Longitude</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>0</td>
                <td id="0">Name 174</td>
                <td id="lat0">41.1230199</td>
                <td id="lng0">14.73767010000006</td>
                <input type="hidden" name="entry[0][name]" value="Name 174">
                <input type="hidden" name="entry[0][lat]" value="41.1230199">
                <input type="hidden" name="entry[0][lng]" value="14.73767010000006">
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

Your controller method will looks like this:

```
public function map(Request $request) {
    foreach ($request->input('entry') as $i => $entry) {
        // here you get an array with:
        // array (3) [
        //     'name' => 'Name 174'
        //     'lat' => '41.1230199'
        //     'lng' => '14.73767010000006'
        // ]
    }
}
```

Comment: How I will use it in the controller ?